# Which emacs shortcuts are useful in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, emacs

Other than `Ctrl+{k, u, a, e}`, what other emacs shortcuts are worth remembering and useful in the Terminal?

Comment: Emacs keybindings are not specific to a terminal, they are used by the shell, most prominently Bash, which uses the GNU Readline library to read input.

Comment: Also see: [Bash Emacs Editing Mode Cheat Sheet](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-emacs-editing-mode-cheat-sheet/).

Comment: As a vi user, I find *no* emacs shortcuts are worth remembering :-) `set -o vi`!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would be difficult to say which shortcuts are worth remembering *for you*, it is entirely dependent on your workflow.  Here is a selection you can go through to decide for yourself:

```
Ctrl-a   Move to the start of the line.
Ctrl-e   Move to the end of the line.
Ctrl-b   Move back one character.
Alt-b    Move back one word.
Ctrl-f   Move forward one character.
Alt-f    Move forward one word.
Ctrl-] x Where x is any character, moves the cursor forward to the next occurrence of x.
Alt-Ctrl-] x Where x is any character, moves the cursor backwards to the previous occurrence of x.
Ctrl-u   Delete from the cursor to the beginning of the line.
Ctrl-k   Delete from the cursor to the end of the line.
Ctrl-w   Delete from the cursor to the start of the word.
Esc-Del  Delete previous word (may not work, instead try Esc followed by Backspace)
Ctrl-y   Pastes text from the buffer (similar to clipboard).
Ctrl-l   Clear the screen leaving the current line at the top of the screen.
Ctrl-x Ctrl-u Undo the last changes. Ctrl-_ does the same
Alt-r    Undo all changes to the line.
Alt-Ctrl-e Expand command line.
Ctrl-r   Incremental reverse search of history.
Alt-p    Non-incremental reverse search of history.
!!       Execute last command in history
!abc     Execute last command in history beginning with abc
!abc:p   Print last command in history beginning with abc
!n       Execute nth command in history
!$       Last argument of last command
!^       First argument of last command
^abc^xyz Replace first occurrence of abc with xyz in last command and execute it
```

Comment: Ctrl-y doesn't paste from clipboard, it [yanks (pastes)](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_keys_basics.html) what you cut with Ctrl-u|k|w (doesn't delete).

Comment: I also found very useful Alt-Backspace (`delete-word`), which is similar to Ctrl-w (`unix-word-rubout`). BTW `bind -p` gives you the current bindings